# Rails 3.1: Creating objects via .build seems to conflict with validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble combining a validation of a foreign key field, and making use of the .build method to create objects. See the classes below.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family
  has_one    :family_user
  validates_presence_of  :name
  validates_associated   :family 
  validates_presence_of  :family_id
end

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :organization
  has_many    :parents
  ...
end
```

This generally works fine, but in the app I want to use the build method. For example, the following code in both a spec and in the rails console fails because it is looking for a family_id on the Parent record.

```
  fam = Family.new(:organization_id => 1)
  fam.children.build(:name => "Billy Jones")
  fam.parents.build(:name => "Mister Jones")
  fam.save!
```

Without `validates_presence_of :family_id` this code works, and indeed a family_id is properly recorded.

Question: is there a way to validate that a family_id is indeed recorded, while also being able to use .build?

For reference, an error in the console is:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :082 > fam = Family.new(:organization_id => 1)
 => #<Family id: nil, organization_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, url_token: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :083 > fam.children.build(:name => "Billy Jones")
 => #<Child id: nil, family_id: nil, name: "Billy Jones", gender: nil, birth_date: nil, desired_start_date: nil, application_date: nil, notes: nil, custom1: nil, custom2: nil, custom3: nil, custom4: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :084 > fam.parents.build(:name => "Mister Jones")
 => #<Parent id: nil, family_id: nil, name: "Mister Jones", address: nil, phone: nil, email: nil, notes: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :085 > fam.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Parents family can't be blank
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
    from (irb):85
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/business/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :086 >
```

Answer (score 0):

I would understand it the same way, at least upon initial reading the code that you have.

Maybe you can try this alternate solution:

http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/74/topics/732

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it seemed to cause more problems. Seems to address issues with `validates_associated` more than `validates_presence_of`.

Comment: An issue is that I'm not certain just what .build triggers. I tried adding `:on => :create`, but I'm shooting in the dark.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in the console, and confirming that just before the call to `.save!` that the `family_id` field is, in deed, set in all of the associated `Parent` objects? It would seem that the obvious answer is "no, it's not set," but if that is true, then the problem is with build, but if it's false, the problem is with the validation.

Comment: I suppose the issue is when the validation is triggered. If I replicate the above console commands with the validation omitted, it writes to the database Family first, then parent and child. The latter two each have the family_id properly included in the SQL. Not sure if there is a way to validate essentially just before writing to the DB?

Comment: That's already what happens - validations are called before anything is saved. Or do you mean, for you to validate the question before anything is saved? If the second situation is the case then you can add a `before_save` and throw a debugger line in there to see the state before anything is written. I think it's the last call to be made before writes are done: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it would work a little different. For example, in the opposite case, validation works as I would hope. I can put `validates :parents, :presence => true` on the Family model and it works as intended. The reverse does not work. I suppose since I build the parent through `Family.parents.build(...)` Family is aware of the parent but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
validates_associated   :family 
validates_presence_of  :family_id
```

and try this

```
validates_presence_of  :family
```

Hope this helps.